# My home modem-router is occupying most subnets

Tags: ports, router

I was port scanning my own isp-issued modem-router and stumbled upon something unsettling: looks like it is listening on ports 554, 7070 & 1863 on (almost) **every** ip of this interval: 192.168.0-255.1

I posted the full port scan on pastebin: [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/wLcnfrA9).

While most of those ip have port 554,7070 & 1863 there are some other ports that are being listened to only on specific subnets:

```
192.168.27.1  | 81/tcp   open  hosts2-ns | 7070/tcp open  realserver
192.168.28.1  | 554/tcp  open  rtsp      | 7070/tcp open  realserver | 8888/tcp open  sun-answerbook
192.168.42.1  | 81/tcp   open  hosts2-ns | 554/tcp  open  rtsp       | 7070/tcp open  realserver
192.168.44.1  | 81/tcp   open  hosts2-ns | 554/tcp  open  rtsp       | 7070/tcp open  realserver
192.168.183.1 | 554/tcp  open  rtsp      | 7070/tcp open  realserver | 8000/tcp open  http-alt
192.168.230.1 | 110/tcp  filtered pop3   | 554/tcp  filtered rtsp    | 1863/tcp filtered msnp  | 7070/tcp filtered realserver
192.168.234.1 | 554/tcp  filtered rtsp   | 1863/tcp filtered msnp    | 3306/tcp filtered mysql | 7070/tcp filtered realserver
```

Here is what I know about this modem:

- It is a CPE by vodafone for use in europe (italy, germany) and NZ marketed as Vodafone Station Revolution or EasyBox 804 (altough this has a different fw from mine).
- Extremely dumbed down web interface implemented as a plugin to Jungo (now Cisco) OpenRG 5.4 (Side question: the linux binaries look like they are from 2005. Is there any known exploit i should be aware of for this version of OpenRG?).

Can the community help me investigate the purpose of these open ports? I think it may be a possible security issue.

Comment: A quick Google search for vodafone and those ports shows 554 = RTSP, 7070 = DVR, 1863 = possibly Xbox.

Comment: @schroeder It may be those ports, but I have never seen a device use all the addresses 192.168.X.1 - why is it using almost 250 subnets? Would those be other user's routers possibly on the ISPs LAN

Comment: No, they cannot be on the ISP (private IP range). My guess is that they forward those ports to make it easier if you subnet your own network. It would reduce troubleshooting calls.

Comment: This modem has some streaming capability provided by dlna/twonky, but i explicitly disabled the feature in the control panel before scanning to be sure to have only the essential services. I will try enabling it and check if new ports show up.

Comment: Looks like they are somehow intercepting those port on wan hosts too. For example if I port scan the "example.com" domain i get port 7070 and 554 open. I don't think those are open on that server. I port scanned again using an online tool this time and those ports are reported as close.

Comment: I have a feeling you have actually scanned beyond your private network and into the carrier's. Could you ping/traceroute the IP addresses and check their TTL?

Comment: @billc.cn I tried, the trace result is [MODEM HOST NAME]>[THE IP]>Lots of timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

Those are ports used in "media" servers- RTSP and realserver are streaming protocols, 1863 is a Microsoft notification protocol. Napster was for file sharing, etc.

Having the router listening on these ports on all internal networks isn't necessarily problematic, though the presence of ancient protocols like realserver and napster is certainly suggestive of age and therefore by implication of security issues.

The two things to look further into are:

- what ports if any are open on the external interface?
- can services listening on internal and external ports be disabled in configuration?

Going through configuration and disabling everything possible to disable should result in there being no listening ports on the external interface and no listening ports except for http (or https) on the internal interface.

There may still be security issues with the internal http port, of greater or lesser difficulty to find. It should be much faster to determine if the minimal level of assurance that unnecessary ports are closed can be achieved. If that level of assurance cannot be achieved then it goes without saying that there will be vulnerabilities on those unnecessarily open ports.

Comment: Those ports are closed on the external interface if scanned with an online tool. I disabled everything but those ports still show up. See my comments to the question for more detail.

Comment: There is another possibility, alluded to in another comment, that those other networks are for other customers of the isp. You might try visiting the gateway IP on one or two other networks and seeing if your personal credentials work.